# Very weird type mismatch in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, variance

Why do I get an error when firing `printGenericType(new Box[Master]())` , and do not get any error in case if I run `printGenericType(new Box())` on `new Box[Master]()`?

```
object VarianceExample extends App {

  new Box[Master]().printGenericType(new Box()) // ok
  new Box().printGenericType(new Box[Master]()) // fail

}

class Box[T >: Tool](implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
  def printGenericType(box: Box[T]) = {
    println(s"Generic type is [$m] - $box")
  }
}

class Master
class Tool   extends Master
class Hammer extends Tool
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define type `T` covariant, otherwise you can pass only the same type you used in constructor. `new Box()`- gives you `Box[Tool]` (without any other constraints) and you are trying to pass `Box[Master]`.

In first example scalac automatically infers `new Box()` as `Box[Master]` because it's in `Box[Master]` position.

Not sure what you want to achieve, but to solve you concrete problem you need to define type Box like this:

```
class Box[+T >: Tool](implicit m: Manifest[T]) {
  def printGenericType[A >: T](box: Box[A]) = {
    println(s"Generic type is [$m] - $box")
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that defining a boundary (`>:`) is an alternative to covariant declaration `-T`.

Comment: My goal was to get a generic type of `box`.

Comment: With (`>:`) you only says that type `T` should be super type of `Tool`, but it doesn't say anything about covariance/contrvariance of this type. You need to specify it explicitly.